# Send variable via php session to form via fancybox 3 ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm trying to pass a variable via php session [FIRST PAGE] to a form called via ajax fancybox [SECOND PAGE] but I only obtain the last value of my array and not the current value I need when selected.

Here the code:

[FIRST PAGE]

```
<?php
session_start();
$africa = array('algeria.png','angola.png', ... );
$africa_length = count($africa);

for($i = 0; $i < $africa_length; $i++){
$replace = str_replace(array(".png", "-"), " ", $africa[$i]);
$return = '<a data-fancybox="ajax" data-src="test.php" data-type="ajax" href="javascript:;">
<div class="international-item">
<div class="flag" style="background:url(img/flags/africa/'.$africa[$i].') no-repeat"></div>
<div class="txt_bold_2 nation">'.$replace.'</div>
</div>
</a>';

echo $return;
$_SESSION['varname'] = $africa[$i];
}
?>
```

[SECOND PAGE]

```
<?php session_start();?>
<form>
...
</form>

<?php
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
echo ($var_value);
?>
```

I need to have the selected nation in [FIRST PAGE] to be passed to the form [SECOND PAGE] so I can insert it in a DB when submitted.

Thx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just have to pass this value for the next page using $_GET. Simply create links like this:

```
data-src="test.php?varname='.$africa[$i].'"
```

Comment: It is correct. Pass value in the url is the best solution for me. Pass it via $_SESSION was too elaborate, as @Arun Kumaresh said "since the loop runs session variable is get updated everytime", I wasn't able to catch the current variable but only the last one in the array.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < $africa_length; $i++){

$_SESSION['varname'][] = $africa[$i];

}
```

since the loop runs session variable is get updated everytime

or you can directly assign array to session variable

```
$_SESSION['varname'] = $africa;
```

Comment: it seems doesn't work. In the loop it returns a fatal error, if directly assign array to session variable it returns the Array to string conversion notice.

Comment: after assigning array to the session variable in the second page print_r($_SESSION) and see what you're geeting